# How to add my password to my pyodbc connection in python

Tags: python, sql-server

I have the following code to connect to my SQL Server database. I am wondering where/how I can add my password so it automatically connects instead of asking for my password.

```
server = 'myserver'
database = 'mydatabase'
username ='johndoe@xyz.com'
Authentication='ADI'
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+
                    ';SERVER='+server+
                    ';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+
                    ';UID='+username+
                    ';AUTHENTICATION='+Authentication
                    )
```

I tried this but it did not work.

```
server = 'myserver'
database = 'mydatabase'
username ='johndoe@xyz.com'
Authentication='ADI'
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+
                    ';SERVER='+server+
                    ';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+
                    ';UID='+username+
                    ';AUTHENTICATION='+Authentication
                    ';PWD= 'MyPassword'
                    )
```

Secondarily, is there another way to have it read my password without putting it in the code itself? If so, I would love any information on that.

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/storing-database-credentials-securely-siddhesh-jog

Comment: @thebjorn, thank you for this! I'll check it out. In the meantime, do you know where in the above code I would my password?

Comment: Look at this (https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Windows) especially the bit about using the ODBC Data Source Administrator to test your parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on pyodbc but this works for mysqldb & psycopg2.

If you are able to use the Environment Variables, you can store information in there and call it using os in your script. Once you have it stored, you can just change your code to something like this below:

```py
import os

server = 'myserver'
database = 'mydatabase'
username ='johndoe@xyz.com'
Authentication='ADI'
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
conn = pyodbc.connect(DRIVER=driver,
                    SERVER=server,
                    PORT=1433,
                    DATABASE=database,
                    UID=username,
                    AUTHENTICATION=Authentication,
                    PWD= os.environ['MYPASSWORD']
                    )
```

Comment: Is there a way that I can just put my current password into the code above and have it run like that?

Comment: Should just be able to do something like 

;PWD='Password123')

If others can view this script though and this is your own password, I would say do not do this

Comment: odd, doesnt seem to be working

Comment: I've updated my answer, give that a shot

Comment: I tried the updated answer but it didn't work. I appreciate your help though!

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me:

```
#def get_connection():
conn = pyodbc.connect(DRIVER= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}',
                    SERVER='ServerName',
                    DATABASE = 'DatabaseName',
                    PORT=PortNumber,
                    Trusted_Connection = 'Yes',
                    UID = 'MyUserName',
                    PWD = 'MyPass',
                    Authentication = 'ActiveDirectoryPassword'
                    )
```